# convert dictionary of lists to another type of list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary of type:

```
Dictionary<Foo,List<Bar>>
```

I would like to convert it to this type:

```
Dictionary<Foo,List<DTOBar>>
```

I have a method called 'ToDTO' which accepts a type Bar and returns a 'DTOBar', to do the conversion

```
DTOBar ToDTO(Bar bar)
{
    return new DTOBar(bar);
}
```

I am able to convert it using one for loop, and then a Select() with a method group like so:

```
foreach (var kvp in GetDict())
{
    var lst = kvp.Value.Select(DTOMapper.ToDTO).ToList();

    ret.Add(kvp.Key,lst);
}
```

Is it possible to reduce this further and do it in a single linq query? I've looked at ToDictionary, but I'm not sure how to break it out of the list from that point. If possible, I'd like to avoid modifying the ToDTO() function (have it still take only a single record and not a List..)

Comment: Sounds like you have everything you need to get this to work, you just need to actually put it together.  Have you *tried* using `ToDictionary` to do this?  What problem(s) do you have with your implementation?

Comment: ToDictionary broke for me when I called ToDTO(), since ToDTO expects a single item and not a list. I see now how I should be doing it. Thanks!

Comment: You *did* have the code to take a list of one type and convert it to the other.  It was right in your question: `kvp.Value.Select(DTOMapper.ToDTO).ToList()`

Comment: ha! I've been spoiled by ReSharper. I'm too dependent on it for writing my linq queries

Comment: Then asking people on SO to write them for you when it fails doesn't help you learn either.  It still leaves you unable to solve very simple problems.  If you take the time to write some attempts yourself, experiment, and learn, then you would be able to solve a problem like this in just a few seconds of your own time.

Comment: That's not true, Servy. I could have got this working myself easily, you're right. But then I would have never learned about the ConvertAll() method. Many times when I don't immediately know something, someone else knows an even better way to do it then I would be able to figure out on my own. After being in this field for long enough, I've learned when I need to humble myself and learn from others. I have no regrets about posting this because now I can use ConvertAll() all over the place. For me that's the whole point of SO, to learn new things. Thanks for your feedback though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GetDict().ToDictionary(
    kvp => kvp.Key,
    kvp => kvp.Value.ConvertAll(DTOMapper.ToDTO)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the 'ConvertAll' method. Besides being obviously more descriptive and therefore readable, is there some other advantage here over the Select? Performance, or.. ?

Comment: @dferraro: It can allocate a result `List<T>` of the correct size.  (`ToList()` on the result of `Select()` doesn't know how big the source is)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ret = GetDict.ToDictionary(
              x => x.Key,
              x => x.Value.Select(DTOMapper.ToDTO).ToList());
```